# why wouldn't a 9-60DCV 20A PWM motor control work to control a 12v 20A wiper motor

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, 12v, motor-controller, rheostat

I have a question regarding controlling the speed of a wiper motor with a PWM vs wiring in a rheostat in the positive side. I have a 110ACV-12DCV 20A converter going to a 9-60DCV 20A PWM motor controller, which is connected to a 12v 20A wiper motor.

I hooked up a multimeter to the potentiometer that came with the MC and theres a 2.5v change in the pot itself but no change in the motor output that goes to the wiper motor, any ideas as to why it wouldn't work, Im using the proper gauge wire going from converter to MC and researched this a lot and everything I've read is to use a PWM rather than using a rheostat in the circuit. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Provide datasheets or manuals for these components.

Comment: ok, ill try and find them and post em real quick, thanks

Comment: Usually wiper motors that have multiple speeds have 4, 5 or 6 wire connections, a single speed machine may not change speed much with  a 2.5v change in supply but it may change the torque - worth checking.

Comment: Related or possible repeat of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453310/12v-dc-motor-controller-to-12v-wiper-motor/ ?

Comment: do you know how to conduct a lab test?, write a lab report?, measure DCR of motor? Vdc output, tell us how you started CCW? or CW? , no load or with load. A 10 A rated DC motor starts with ~ 100A until it spins whereas a 14.2V car wiper motor with a 10A fuse is not what you said, but is what I guess.  details, details ....

Comment: The pot is likely a 555 PWM circuit

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.